# VS Code fallback DOM integrated terminal ignores cursor style settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I started up VS Code code today, it recommended that I switch back to the old DOM integrated terminal renderer, [as described here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_integrated-terminal), since the new renderer was not performing well on my system. So my settings now include the following:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
    "terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line"
}
```

However, with the old DOM integrated terminal renderer, the `cursorBlinking` and `cursorStyle` settings seem to be ignored. My integrated terminal now uses an unblinking block cursor. Is there a fix for this?

**System Info:**
Ubuntu 18.04
VS Code 1.24.1

Answer (score 0):

This was probably a bug.

For the blinking issue, probably [integrated terminal: cursor blinking dosen't work with render type dom #70749](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70749).

For the style issue, I'm not sure, but perhaps the follow are related: [Terminal cursor style changes on blink #77559](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77559), [Terminal Cursor Size/Position incorrect when using DOM renderer
#50125](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50125)

The above found by googling "`github vscode issues terminal dom renderer cursor style "bug"`".